# async() in angular unit tests not resolving the promises in its zone

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await

I have an unit test like this.

```
it('check no of users', async(() => {
  userService
       .getUsers()
       .toPromise()
       .then((noOfusers) => {
          console.log(noOfUsers);
          expect(noOfUsers.length).toBeEqual(5)
       })
       .catch(err);
}));
```

This test is always passing, its neither printing the console.log or checking the expect statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will something like this work? `var result = await userService.getUsers().toPromise(); expect(result.length).toBeEqual(5);`

Comment: Its maibe that you are passing in the catch. You should console.log the err